# Embed YouTube HTML5 Video

Tags: html, video, youtube, youtube-api

I've got a modern web-application which doesn't work beyond IE 9 so I'm looking for a better way to embed the HTML5 version of YouTube-videos than using the iframe-code.

I tried the new `<embed>`-element but it keeps bringing up the Flash-player even in my Chrome 42 so **what's the best way to embed my YouTube (and Vimeo) videos in my homepage?**

I don't want to add another JS-library.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best way, but it works with your embed tag.

Lets say this is your link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BbnRDXHVBUQ

change it to this: https://www.youtube.com/embed/BbnRDXHVBUQ

and embed it like this:

```
<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BbnRDXHVBUQ" width="640px" height="320px">
```